# read from 32bit record in 64bit project

Tags: delphi, 64-bit

I have got an old project to refactor.
This is Delphi5 project in 32bit.

The new project must use 64bit architecture.

Actually my point is to read old data format from a file.

The file contains records with lot of fields.

At the moment I have problem with dynamic array of integers.

```
TCObject = record
  Name:string[205];
  roomindex:array of integer;
```

SizeOf(roomindex) = 4 in old project 
and
SizeOf(roomindex) = 8 in my 64bit project.

So I have a problem to read data from file as

```
stream.Read(buf, SizeOf(TCObject))
```

Could you show me way how to say Delphi to use size=4? :)

Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE:** 
as David said it is better to provide real code that reads data.

```
procedure ParseCDatabase(pBuff: Pointer; pSize: Integer);
var
  curr:^TCObject;
  i, n: Integer;
  curri:^Integer;
begin
  curri:= pBuff;
  n:=curri^;
  Inc(curri);
  curr:=pointer(curri);
  for i:=0 to n-1 do 
  begin
    if Curr^.Name<>'' then 
    begin
      COAddObject();
      curro:=pointer(curr);
      curro.RoomIndex:=integer(nil);
      Fcodb[af][ai]:=curr^;
      SetLength(Fcodb[af][ai].RoomIndex,0);
      Inc(ai);
    end;
    inc(curr);
  end;
end;
```

I provide code as is... So we see here that roomindex is read but reset to 0.
So actualy we do not need it at all.

Problem is to read whole data via pointers because size of point to dynamic array is 8 now but not 4.

Comment: You aren't telling us the whole story here. Your code that you claim works in Delphi 5 does not work. You cannot store pointers directly to file because they only have meaning in the executing process. `stream.Read(buf, SizeOf(TCObject))` has never worked in any version of Delphi. You'll need to dig deeper and find out what the program really does when persisting this record. Posting fake code that bears no relation to the real code is seriously unhelpful. You've asked this question way too early. You really need to knuckle down and understand the problem first. Don't expect short cuts here.

Comment: Hmm, I wouldn't start from here! But you don't have any choice do you. Probably Dsm's approach is sound.

Comment: @DavidHeffernanI updated my question with real code from old project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

roomindex is a pointer, which in a 32 bit project is 4 bytes and in a 64 bit project is 8 bytes. You can't change that realistically. I am amazed that you save a pointer to a file, and load it back. How can that work, unless the pointer is discarded? Assuming you save the pointer but discard it you can do this:

```
TCObjectOldFormat = record
  Name:string[205];
  roomindex: Int32;
end;

TCObject = record
  Name:string[205];
  roomindex:array of integer; 
end;

var
  AObject : TCObject;
  AObjectOldFormat :TCObjectOldFormat;
...
stream.ReadBuffer(AObjectOldFormat, SizeOf(TCObjectOldFormat));
AObject.Name := AOldObject.Name;
```

obvious you can adapt to your needs using buf. This just shows more explicitly the idea.

Comment: "I am amazed that you save a pointer to a file." It is not my code and I do not like it. It is critically old-schooled with procedural style and so on. My task is to refactor it to get readable code.

Comment: your answer is appreciated. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Your welcome. I meant no criticism of you, only the code.